# Why did Aramaki only speak in Japanese?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell-2017

Throughout the live action version of *Ghost in the Shell*, Chief Aramaki spoke only in Japanese the whole time, whereas nearly every other character spoke in English. Is there an in-universe or production reason for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speaking different languages in a movie](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71570/speaking-different-languages-in-a-movie)

Comment: @BlueMoon93 I wouldn't say a duplicate since it was asked first.

Comment: @LeonFreire When two unanswered questions are there, it doesn't matter which question is asked earlier. It depends on which question is more clear and which has better answer.

Comment: @SS Oh, I see. Didn't know that. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an interview the actor gave to *Today Cinema*:

> "I demanded (to the director) that Aramaki needed to speak in Japanese and I carried it through. Because the
>   based film is a Japanese anime. I was happy to join a film based on a Japanese-born work. But on the technology
>   side, I was amazed by Hollywood.

source : http://www.crunchyroll.com/anime-news/2017/03/16-1/beat-takeshi-ghost-in-the-shell-may-be-first-successful-live-action-film-adaptation-of-japanese-manga

Comment: Just a homage thing which I find really nice. I hate it when US gets another country's story and completely spray US all over it without a single homage to the story's origin. In other words, _white wash_ the whole thing.