# Speaking different languages in Ghost in the Shell

Tags: dialogue, ghost-in-the-shell-2017

Just watched [Ghost in the Shell](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1219827/), a movie inspired by [its Anime counterpart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_in_the_Shell), and occurring in Hong Kong. Being a movie on a non-english country, usually one of two things happen:

- Movie is (almost) entirely in english
- Movie is entirely in foreign language

With american actors, the first option was the obvious go-to. In these cases, it is frequent to show the characters starting to speak the foreign language (just for a couple of sentences), and then switch to English. **The idea is to convey to the user that they are speaking another language but that it is understandable to the characters, just like English is to the viewers.**

In fact, sometimes the opposite is done, where characters speak foreign languages without subtitles to give the viewer the sensation of hostility or confusion (see [Mad Max](http://madmax.wikia.com/wiki/The_Buzzards) or [Arrival](https://www.thrillist.com/entertainment/nation/arrival-chinese-line-ending)).

However, in Ghost in the Shell, [some characters](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0010866/?ref_=tt_cl_t3) only speak in Chinese (or Japanese?), while all others go for English. **Why?**

It doesn't seem that they are both speaking the same foreign language. The Asian actor is the only one speaking constantly in Chinese. Subtitles appear on his lines, so the viewer is meant to understand them, just like the characters.

### Is the language used meant to be literally interpreted (e.g., they are actually speaking English and Chinese to each other)? Or is there some perspective being conveyed to the viewers?

In the former, why would the *Public Security Section 9* speak English most of the time? In the latter, why this approach with only specific characters speaking the foreign language?

Comment: Considering that there was an "universal translator augmentation" (or something similar) advertisement at the beginning of the film, I'd say that all of the characters understand each other perfectly well regardless of their spoken languages. But we (audience) don't have this augmentation, so we hear languages they use as the most natural to them.

Comment: There was? O.o I think I missed that...

Comment: But it was Japanese, just as a simple correction. And that is because it is based on an anime so its probably a homage thing.